# preg_match to remove forbidden chars?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to remove forbidden chars from a string.

```
$forbidden = array( "<", ">", "{", "}", "[", "]", "(", ")", "select", "update", "delete", "insert", "drop", "concat", "script");
foreach ($forbidden as $forbidChar) {
    if (preg_match("/$forbidChar/i", $string)) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

But it's not working as expected, where did I go wrong?

Comment: You have regex metacharacters in `$forbidden`. It won't work unless you escape them. Also, this can be done in a single regex.

Comment: look into `preg_replace`, and write `"/$forbidChar/i"` either like this: `'/'.$forbidChar.'/i'`, I'm not sure if it's an issue here, but the `$` sign is not meaningless inside an expression, so it might cause ambiguity here, possibly `"/{$forbidChar}/i"` would work, but the curly braces could also be regarded as ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a single regex like this:

```
$forbidden = array(
            "<", ">", "{", "}", "[", "]", "(", ")",
            "select", "update", "delete", "insert", "drop", "concat", "script");
$forbidden = array_map( 'preg_quote', $forbidden, array_fill( 0, count( $forbidden), '/'));
return (bool) preg_match( '/' . implode( '|', $forbidden) . '/', $string);
```

This properly escapes all of the characters with `preg_quote()`, and forms a single regex to test for all of the cases.

<sub>Note: I haven't tested it, but it should work.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `preg_replace()` if you want characters to be replaced. **Not** `preg_match()`.

You may also want to ensure that your forbidden characters are properly escaped using `preg_quote()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I dont want them to be replaced, I only want to return whether or not there's a forbidden character.

Comment: @Sarah In that case, use `preg_quote()` before passing the variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the character `"[", "]", "(", ")" with "\[", "\]", "\)", "\)"`

Here is the working code,

```
<?php 
$string = "dfds fdsf dsfs fkldsk  select dsasd asdasd";
$forbidden = array(
            "<", ">", "{", "}", "\[", "\]", "\(", "\)",
            "select", "update", "delete", "insert", "drop", "concat", "script");
   foreach ($forbidden as $forbidChar) {
        if (preg_match("/$forbidChar/i", $string)) {
            exit('Forbidden char dtected');
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
?>
```

Comment: I used preg_quote() to escape the characters.

Comment: Okay. preg_quote() is best to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the performanter [string_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) function to do this

```
<?php
   $forbidden = array(
        "<", ">", "{", "}", "[", "]", "(", ")",
        "select", "update", "delete", "insert", "drop", "concat", "script");
   
    $cleanString = str_ireplace($forbidden, "", $string);
?>
```